# Cross-quantilogram method

Tags: frequency-spectrum, cross-correlation, correlation, quantization, variational-methods

1. What is this method in general?
2. What is the main difference between the quantile cross-spectrum (QS) approach developed by Baruník and Kley (2019) and the cross-correlation function (QS) developed by Han et al. (2016)?
3. Also, through which program can I use this method?

Comment: Hi! Welcome here!
Your first question sounds… very very broad. Since I haven't heard of it, and my internet search engine turns up empty for "cross-quantitogram",  I doubt many will, you probably are in a better position than us to research that yourself. Please explain what you know and understand about it, and where exactly you need help with understanding

Comment: Did you mean "quantilogram?" [Here is some documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantilogram/quantilogram.pdf) for the statistical software R.

Comment: Hi gurbuz, in your title you used "quan**tito**gram", in the original version of your text "quan**to**gram", and not it seems likely you meant "quan**tilo**gram". Could you please confirm that you mean quan**tilo**gram?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes, I said "quantilogram".